# Unable to resolve Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I know there are a ton of threads on this already.  I've read many of them and tried the solutions in them, all to no avail.

Here's what I've got in my head:

```
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/jquery.inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Plugins/PNotify/pnotify.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/IRF/Scripts/CustomModules/app-notifications.js"></script>
```

And some CSS files:

```
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Content/typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Plugins/PNotify/pnotify.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Content/irf-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Areas/IRF/Plugins/Qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ... some stuff
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.RequestedResponseDate').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            startDate: '-3d'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally...

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input class="form-control datepicker valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Requested Response Date must be a date." id="RequestedResponseDate" name="RequestedResponseDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" value="" aria-describedby="RequestedResponseDate-error">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am getting this error:

```
New:514 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    (anonymous function) @ New:514fire @ jquery-2.1.3.js:3094
    self.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.3.js:3206
    jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.3.js:3412
    completed @ jquery-2.1.3.js:3428
```

I have tried to re-order where the ref to jquery-2.1.3.js is located (moving it down) but that just causes other problems.  I have also tried adding         $.noConflict();

```
    $.noConflict();
    $(function () {
        $('.RequestedResponseDate').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            startDate: '-3d'
        });
```

But then the same error shows up twice!

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
(anonymous function) @ New:514
```

Comment: Check if the file is icluded

Comment: Where is `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` coming from

Comment: Kevin, not sure what  you mean

Comment: giannis, yes, the file is included.  If not there would be 404 errors in the console window

Comment: @CaseyCrookston link to a github url for that file. What is it? where did you get it? where is datepicker defined?

Comment: It looks like your including a `datetimepicker.js` file, which would imply there is a datetimepicker() method, not a datepicker() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being a missing reference to jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `bootstrap-datepicker.js` instead of `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`.

They are different plugins